# Same VRRP group, multiple VLAN

Tags: vlan, redundancy, vrrp

Let's say a gateway has traffic between vlan 11 and 22:

```
Gateway 1 -- FastEthernet 0/1.1 -- vlan 11 -- 192.168.11.1
Gateway 1 -- FastEthernet 0/2.2 -- vlan 22 -- 192.168.22.1

Gateway 2 -- FastEthernet 0/1.1 -- vlan 11 -- 192.168.11.2
Gateway 2 -- FastEthernet 0/2.2 -- vlan 22 -- 192.168.22.2
```

Obviously, **the main point here** is both 0/1.1 and 0/2.2 should both switch in case of fail over, always together at the same time, so i think i should configure just ONE VRRP group like this:

```
FastEthernet 0/1.1 -- vrrp 1 ip 192.168.11.3
FastEthernet 0/2.2 -- vrrp 1 ip 192.168.22.3
```

So the following is confusing me:

**Q1)** If just port 0/1.1 fail (vlan 11), then both 11 and 22 will switchover to backup?

**Q2)** Could the same VRRP group handle more than one IP?

**Q3)** Will this work at all, or is there any other way?

Comment: If you feel this doesn't attract good enough answers here - try http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have got the answer!

**A2)** [It depends](https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2092248) on the model firmware and vendor, but lately they do NOT allow to have more than one IP or IF in the same VRRP group and it will throw an error (Juniper, Cisco, etc).

**A3)** Even if you could, you shouldn't reuse the same VRRP group. Instead you should have many groups and play with their [priorities](https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2101036). Yes, this can be large work to configure.

**A1)** You should [track](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipapp_fhrp/configuration/12-4/fhp-vrrp.html#GUID-A6F936CD-71DF-4407-A943-3BD35389049A) the interface 0/1.1 and decrement the priority of the other 0/2.2, and viceversa.

Comment: Another way that turned out to be better, is to use EEM scripts: create just one VRRP group on the private interface, and bring the public interface up/down automatically! This way you only waste one public IP. [link](http://mellowd.co.uk/ccie/?p=3180)